# Make UITableview cell transparent when it get selected

Tags: uitableview

How to remove selection style color of UITableview while i select a particular cell ? When i change the selection style of cell to **UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone**, the highlighted image doesn't appear in the cell. When i change that to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue or UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGrey, the highlighted cell will distort will that particular gray or blue. My requirement is to make the cell with transparent background and when it gets selected, the selected image must show without selection style color.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. Just put the below code inside cellForRowAtIndexpath method of willDisplayCell method

```
UIView *backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.backgroundView = backView;
cell.selectedBackgroundView = backView;
```

Answer (score -1):

For customizing the selected cell background and its controls state, you needs to override the following method..

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: That’s not a delegate method, it’s a UITableViewCell method…